# Getting a binding property exception when loading the yml file into an object

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, yaml

I am trying to load a yml file with the following element into an object in a test class

yml file name is application-acl-config.yml and there are more yml files in the folder. I assume spring boot merges all of them into one when the application starts.

yml file in resources of main folder:

```
  logicalClientIdentifiers:
    -   applicationIdentifier:
            applicationId: x
            logicalClientIds:
            - x
    -   applicationIdentifier:
            applicationId: y
            logicalClientIds:
            - y
```

code in main folder for pojo class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "logicalClientIdentifiers")
public class LogicalClientIdentifiers{
        private class ApplicationIdentifier {
            private String applicationId;
            private List<String> logicalClientIds;

            public String getApplicationId() {
                return applicationId;
            }

            public void setApplicationId(String applicationId) {
                this.applicationId = applicationId;
            }

            public List<String> getLogicalClientIds() {
                return logicalClientIds;
            }

            public void setLogicalClientIds(List<String> logicalClientIds) {
                this.logicalClientIds = logicalClientIds;
            }
        }

        private List<ApplicationIdentifier> applicationIdentifiers;

        public List<ApplicationIdentifier> getApplicationIdentifiers() {
            return applicationIdentifiers;
        }

        public void setApplicationIdentifiers(List<ApplicationIdentifier> applicationIdentifiers) {
            this.applicationIdentifiers = applicationIdentifiers;
        }

    }
```

test code in test folder:

```
@RunWith(value = SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = LogicalClientIdentifiers.class, initializers = ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer.class)
public class ChannelAuthorizationTest {

    @Autowired
    LogicalClientIdentifiers applicationAclConfigProps;


    @Test
    public void test(){
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

I am getting this exception:

```
`Caused by: org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindException: Error creating bean with name 'logicalClientIdentifiers': Could not bind properties to 'LogicalClientIdentifiers' : prefix=logicalClientIdentifiers, ignoreInvalidFields=false, ignoreUnknownFields=true; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.properties.source.InvalidConfigurationPropertyNameException: Configuration property name 'logicalClientIdentifiers' is not` valid
```

I believe I am not creating the pojo properly to parse the yml file or the yml file is not being referenced properly.

Answer (score 0):

Your Java class looks like you want to load this YAML:

```yaml
logicalClientIdentifiers:
  applicationIdentifiers:
  - applicationId: x
    logicalClientIds:
    - x
  - applicationId: y
    logicalClientIds:
    - y
```

You need to be careful that the YAML structure and your class structure match. The YAML you show misses the `applicationIdentifiers` field in the class `LogicalClientIdentifiers` and instead contains a sequence of mappings where each contains only a key `applicationIdentifier`, which does not map to anything in your Java classes.

Your error message occurs because you specify an invalid prefix. As [described in the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-relaxed-binding),

> The prefix value for the annotation must be in kebab case (lowercase and separated by -, such as acme.my-project.person).

so you have to use `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "logical-client-identifiers")`.

Comment: @Fernando: Since your YAML directly contains a sequence at the path indicated by the prefix, you would need some `List<ApplicationIdentifierWrapper>` where that wrapper contains the field `ApplicationIdentifier applicationIdentifier` but I don't know enough about Spring Boot to tell you how you'd apply `@ConfigurationProperties` on a `List<>` instance.